# Утеря key store для signed apk

Tags: java, android, google-play

Что будет, если случайно key store, которым подписано signed apk (которое в продакшине) потеряется/удалится?  Можно будет ли потом сгенирировать новый key store для следующих версий приложения и подписать приложение ним? И примет ли такое приложение *Google Play*?

Comment: Вы не сможете обновлять свое приложение и вам придется выпустить другое приложение (с другим именем)

Comment: @pavlofff а разве другого пакета недостаточно?

Comment: @Kostya фактически это и будет другое приложение (с другим именем), даже если код один и тот же и делает оно то же самое

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нет. Новый ключ вы можете сгенерировать, но они будут разные. Гугл не примет обновление вашего приложения, если оно будет подписано другим ключём.

Поэтому залейте ключ во все облака куда только можете :)

Comment: Спасибо, я так и подумала, но решила уточнить на всякий случай!